# Can python37.dll suddenly become a malware?

Tags: python, dll, malware

On my computer I have a few conda environments. I was running my pycharm project using one of them. I use this environment for the last few months, but today, out of nowhere, malwarebytes (my antivirus program) has sent python37.dll from that environment into quarantine. I clicked on malwarebytes' list of quarantined files, and it directed me to [this website](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/detections/malware-ai/), explaining that their AI made such decision.

But as I said, I have many envs with python37.dll and they weren't quarantined. I use them normally. What's interesting,when I used conda clone command on the env that had the "suspicious dll", the dll from the newly created environment was also immediately sent to the quarantine.

Does this happen to people, that python37.dll sometimes becomes corrupt and malicious? Or is it malwarebytes getting buggy?

What may be happening?

Comment: Maybe try uploading the file to VirusTotal and see if it's flagged? I would imagine that if a Python dll is infected with malware, that you have some other kind of malware on your system that's affecting other files. It would be helpful to know the exact malware variant that was detected. Is the suspicious DLL a different size than the other Python 3.7 DLLs?

Comment: Some other malware could have changed the contents of the file, or replaced it. At any rate, this is a question about a problem you are having with your computer, not a question about writing code. It is thus off topic here. You might be able to get an answer on https://superuser.com, but I think you want an actual support forum - either for the MalwareBytes software or for your operating system.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities here: either your antivirus made a wrong judgement or that DLL really contains malicious code.

Since antivirus programs are based on various heuristics, even if a binary file was flagged as a virus, it doesn't really prove that the file really has some malicious code.
It might as well be a false alarm.

At the same time, there are viruses out there that can overwrite various binary files in your system and add malicious code to the existing files.
So there is a technical possibility that this file might really have malicious code.

I'd suggest to download a fresh python37.dll file from the official conda website, calculate SHA-256 hash of it and compare it with the file you have on your computer.
This way you will know if your python37.dll file was really altered or not.